# VSCode - Disable auto open files on drag and drop

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I drag and drop a file it always opens in new tab, I need to know how can I disable this.

Thanks.

Comment: By the way I need to disable this because of .jar files.

Comment: Please I need an answer to know if there is an option that I am missing or if people are asking for this.